# Generalized PDF - Delta function clarification of understanding

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Letting $X$ be a discrete random variable with PMF $P_{X}(x_k)$, the $CDF(X)$ of $$
\mathrm{F}_{X}\left(x\right) =
\sum_{x_{k}\ \in\ R_{X}}\mathrm{P}_{X}\left(x_k\right)
\,\mathrm{u}\left(x - x_{k}\right)\,,
$$
then $\displaystyle{\operatorname{PDF}\left(X\right) = \mathrm{f}_{X}\left(x\right) =
\!\!\!\sum_{x_{k}\ \in\ R_{X}}\,\,\mathrm{P}_{X}\left(x_{k}\right)
\delta\left(x - x_{k}\right)}$ by taking the derivative.

But isn't this just $\infty$ for each $x_k$ by definition of the delta function ?.

Comment: If you fancy looking at actual mathematical definitions, you should soon realize that the PDF of such a random variable X does not exist. There is nothing to gain to introduce "generalized PDFs", a phrase whose meaning is mostly "not a true PDF but we do not know what it is exactly", and everything to learn the subject properly...

Comment: The "definition" $\delta(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x \neq 0 \\ \infty & x=0 \end{cases}$ is really not a very useful definition. It is useful as a visualization tool, and for understanding how to approximate the delta function by continuous functions, but that's about the extent of it. Two better definitions of the delta function are "the measure $\delta(A)=\begin{cases} 1 & 0 \in A \\ 0 & 0 \not \in A \end{cases}$" and "the functional $\delta(f)=f(0)$". Both of these allow you to make proper sense of $c \delta$ for constants $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)dx=1$$

Assume the $f_X(x)$ has a $\delta$ at $x_k$. When using pdf to calculate $P(X=x_k)$:

$$P(X=x_k)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{x_k-\epsilon}^{x_k+\epsilon}f_X(x_k)dx$$ and 
therefore, although $\delta(x-x_k)=\infty$ at $x=x_k$, it is always inside the integral and the result is just a number.

Also note that for discrete RV $X$ the pdf is $$\sum_{x_k}P(X=x_k)\delta(x-x_k)$$
 However, the probability $P(X=x_k)$ is the coefficient of $\delta(x-x_k)$ not the value of $\delta$. That's why sometimes PMF is used for simplicity which is just a discrete series corresponding to discrete probabilities $P(X=x_k)$.

Comment: At least two $dx$ missing, even within the context of the extremely lax conventions used in this post.